# How do I ensure R / Rcpp code is reproducible ("distributable")?

Tags: r, rcpp, future-proof

I've written some R code for a dissertation, relying on some external packages (e.g., `plyr` and `reshape`) and writing a couple relatively simple inline C++ functions using `inline` and `RcppArmadillo`.

I would like to ensure it can be performed "as is" on computers others than my own (Win64), for research reproducibility purposes.

My question: suppose I included code for installing the required packages, would the `RcppArmadillo` (and `Rcpp` and `inline`) packages be sufficient to be able to compile the functions written in `RcppArmadillo`, or would the end user need to change system paths for compilation on his Windows machine? If not, is it possible/recommended to saved the compiled functions from my end and included in the R code I'm shipping?

Also, in the unlikely case that the code should be run some time later (say, a couple of years), is it suffient to include a full R installation with the relevant packages in their current version to make the code "future-proof"?

I hope the question is clear.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I think you mean your code to be "distributable" and "executable by someone else" which is a looser requirement.  Being "reproducible" implies that the previous question is a true, and adds the restriction that the results are identical (up to the an epsilon of your choice).

And the usual answer for 'how can I let others run my R code' is to create a package.

For Rcpp-related code, we have an entire vignette devoted to building your own package with your Rcpp-using cod.  The vignette is called 'Rcpp-package'.

Comment: Thank you, I was not aware of the distinction between "reproducible" and "distributable". As you probably guessed, I meant the latter.
I half-expected the answer would be "create a package", which to me seems like dignifying my code a bit too much, but if that's the easiest, most documented solution, I'll do that.

Comment: I voted up for the distinction about "reproducible" and "distributable". I didn't know it either.